# What is the use of this case of scalaz.Ordering?

Tags: scala, scalaz

Reading http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Order.html this example is given :

```
scala> 1.0 ?|? 2.0
res10: scalaz.Ordering = LT
```

All that is stated with regard to Ordering is :

"

```
scala> 1 > 2.0
res8: Boolean = false

scala> 1 gt 2.0
<console>:14: error: could not find implicit value for parameter F0: scalaz.Order[Any]
              1 gt 2.0
              ^

scala> 1.0 ?|? 2.0
res10: scalaz.Ordering = LT

scala> 1.0 max 2.0
res11: Double = 2.0

Order enables ?|? syntax which returns Ordering: LT, GT, and EQ. It also enables lt, gt, lte, gte, min, and max operators by declaring order method. Similar to Equal, comparing Int and Doubl fails compilation.
```

"

What is the significance of scalaz.Ordering in this case ?

1.0 max 2.0 is using standard Scala API max method and does not relate to scalaz ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scalaz [does provide this syntax](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/syntax/OrderSyntax.scala#L11) for things with an `Order` instance. You're right in this case that `1.0 max 2.0` will use the `max` from the standard library, though, since it's more specific (as you can quickly confirm by starting up power mode with `:power` in the REPL and then entering something like `settings.processArgumentString("-print typer")`).

A better example in this case would be something like `some(2.0) max some(1.0)`, since the standard library doesn't provide a `max` for `Option[Double]` that would hide Scalaz's.

Comment: thanks for the example "some(2.0) max some(1.0)" , very useful

Answer (score 0):

[Tom Switzer puts it concisely in a related thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scalaz/0hP6BGzWAHQ/6MyAH_s19_0J):

> Instead of returning an `Int` from `Order#compare`, scalaz returns a
>   `scalaz.Ordering`.